# Upgrading from struts1.0 to struts2.3.16.1

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, struts1

We have a running JSP project using Struts 1.0. Its a pretty big project. We want to upgrade the project in Struts 2.3.16.1. As I am new in struts framework I am not sure who much  changes will be needed for this upgrade. Will it be a good idea to upgrade to 2.3.16.1 direct from  version 1.0 as 1.0 is a very primitive version.

Comment: S2 and S1 are completely different frameworks. On the plus side, it means you don't need to bother running through S1.x upgrades along the way. On the negative side, ugh. If you want to rewrite the app you'd be just as well off choosing *any* technology you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This links [Migration Guide](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-guide.html) and [Migration Strategy](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-strategies.html) may help you. But you have to do lots of R&D stuff on it. It just like making a brand new application.

Thanks.